# Applying OR predicate Java 8

Tags: java, filter, java-8, predicate

I have employee object

```
public class Employee {

    public Employee(Integer id, Integer age, String gender, String fName, String lName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    private Integer id;
    private Integer age;
    private String gender;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
```

I have two predicates

```
public static Predicate<Employee> firstNameLike(final String name) {
        return p -> p.getFirstName().contains(name);
    }


    public static Predicate<Employee> isAdultFemale() {
        return p -> p.getAge() > 18 && p.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("F");
    }
```

*I am applying multiple filters to the employees e.g.*

```
public class TestEmployeePredicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, 13, "F", "Martina", "Hengis");
        Employee e5 = new Employee(5, 19, "F", "Cristine", "Maria");
        Employee e7 = new Employee(7, 68, "F", "Melissa", "Roy");
        Employee e9 = new Employee(9, 15, "F", "Neetu", "Singh");


        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, 23, "M", "Rick", "Beethovan");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, 43, "M", "Ricky", "Martin");
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, 26, "M", "Jon", "Lowman");
        Employee e6 = new Employee(6, 15, "M", "David", "Feezor");
        Employee e8 = new Employee(8, 79, "M", "Alex", "Gussin");
        Employee e10 = new Employee(10, 45, "M", "Naveen", "Jain");


        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employees.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Employee[]{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10}));


        List<Predicate<Employee>> predicates = new ArrayList<>();


        predicates.add(EmployeePredicates.isAdultFemale());
        predicates.add(EmployeePredicates.firstNameLike("J"));


        final Predicate<Employee> employeePredicate = predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).get();

        //OR adult male
        employeePredicate.or(EmployeePredicates.isAdultMale());


        final List<Employee> collect = employees.stream().filter(employeePredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(collect.size());
```

As per my logic it should check the list

if its `AdultFemale` and `firstname like "J"` OR its `Adult Male`

But This is not working as per the logic. What I am doing wrong here? Even if the employee is Adult MALE its filtering out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or-java.util.function.Predicate-) does not alter the `Predicate` object it's used on, it **returns** a `Predicate` with that logic. Here, since you haven't assigned the return value anywhere you've just lost it, and the `or` call does nothing. Instead, you should save it to a variable. E.g.:

```
final Predicate<Employee> employeePredicate = 
    predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).get();

// OR adult male
// Note that the result is saved back to employeePredicate
employeePredicate = employeePredicate.or(EmployeePredicates.isAdultMale());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I wish I had a look at the API itself ! Thanks a lot. I am new to Java 8